# I need to add LSTM layer with CNN model

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm

```
def create_model():
  time_start = datetime.now()
  number_of_images = 16222
  cnn = Sequential()

  cnn.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(50, 100, 1)))
  cnn.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides= 2))
  cnn.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides= 2))

  cnn.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides= 2))

  cnn.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides= 1))


  cnn.add(SpatialPyramidPooling([1, 2, 4]))
  # model.add(Flatten())
  # model.add(Reshape(14000))
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(None, 50, 100, 1)))
  # model.add(Reshape(10752))
  model.add(LSTM(10752)) 
  # model.add(ConvLSTM2D(512,kernel_size=(3,3),return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
  model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))  
  model.add(Dense(604, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I am working on image classification project, and I want to add an LSTM layer to the CNN model. but I am facing problems. below my model

Comment: Could you please explain what problems you are facing?

Comment: my X_train.shape = x_train (14599, 100, 200, 1), the output dimension = 604 ,,, this is the error
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4,,,, I tried to use the reshape layer: model.add(Reshape(input_shape=(50, 100), target_shape = (100, 604) )), but I didn't know what parameters I needed to put it.

Comment: plz help me to find the solution